# Data spread is good or bad in machine learning , and why

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

I am new in machine learning and I know a standard deviation is a number that describes how spread data but if the spread is high is good for model or not and how we fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) says:

> the standard deviation is a measure of the amount of variation or dispersion of a set of values. A low standard deviation indicates that the values tend to be close to the mean (also called the expected value) of the set, while a high standard deviation indicates that the values are spread out over a wider range.

This means that generally standard deviation is just a statistic that contains some information about the distribution of your data. Since there are many branches and fields in machine learning, it's not very correct to say we desire the data to be spread or concentrated.

In some applications like classification, if the data of each class is more concentrated around the mean (provided the classes have different means), you can classify them with higher accuracy.

You can simply lower the standard deviation of your whole data by dividing it by some number, but that would also lower the distance between your class centers which means this would not benefit you in any way.